# Как реализовать позиционирование элементов в зависимости от их порядкового номера?

Tags: css, css3

У меня есть блок.

```
<div class="elements">
 <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

Кол-во элементов `<div class="element"></div>` неизвестно. Расположить их мне нужно в случайном порядке в рамках родителя.

Как это реализовать можно на чистом css ?

Comment: Что значит "в случайном порядке"?

Comment: `css` - это вам не язык программирования и перемешать элементы в случайном порядке невозможно на чистом `css`, вам нужен `js` или другой иной язык программирования.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15327990/generate-random-color-with-pure-css-no-javascript

Answer (score 1):

В общем на чистом `CSS` этого сделать не получится, но можно попробовать использовать `SCSS`. Но всё равно есть ограничения. Без использования js у Вас не получится определить количество Элементов на странице. Но тут всё зависит от задачи которая у Вас возникла. Если это вывод каких-то записей, то Вы по-любому должны добавлять пагинацию и т.д. Просто слово неизвестно всё равно имеет ограничение. Поэтому определите максимум который будет выводится на странице, и далее сделайте следующее [мой вариант решения на css](https://jsfiddle.net/gfhj1yck/1/). Код Ниже. При каждой загрузке страницы элементы с классом `element` будут выводиться в случайном порядке! И ограничение на кол-во элементов в 100 штук у меня. Но по мне так проще и надёжнее с помощью js реализовать если они грузятся через ajax. Либо с помощью бэк языка, которым выводите данные (пример php функция `shuffle`).

```css
.elements {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  $a : random(300);
  & .element {
    height: 25px;
    @for $i from 1 through 100     {
      &:nth-child(#{$i}) {            
        order: random($i + $a); 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="elements">
 <div class="element">1</div>
  <div class="element">2</div>
  <div class="element">3</div>
  <div class="element">4</div>
  <div class="element">5</div>
  <div class="element">6</div>
  <div class="element">7</div>
  <div class="element">8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не проще-ли, делать это через `js`? раз все равно на клиенте ему нужно. Это будет куда проще сделать, нежели подключать тонну файлов и настроек....

Comment: @And проще и правильнее. Я так и написал в конце. Что лучше использовать js или бэк. Автор спросил можно ли на css, я предложил такое решение, если уж из принципа использовать css.